# Cannot boot pfSense USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios, ahci

I've got a mini PC ([Qotom
quad core Mini PC Q190P](http://www.qotom.net/goods-128-Q190P+with+4+COM+Ports.html)) that I can not seem to get to boot the pfSense installation, despite other machines being able to boot from the same media, and this machine being able to boot other media.

Following the [pfSense doc](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Writing_Disk_Images)s, I have tried using Rufus, Win32DiskImager, and plain old dd, all with no success.

I have be able to get the pfSense USB to boot on both my desktop, i7, and laptop, i5, so I know the installation media is bootable, this means it must be bios configuration on the mini pc.

I have tried almost all combinations of AHCI / IDE, and forced usb boot settings, and boot orders that I can think of, and I an unable to get it to read the media.

This machine is currently running CentOS7 64 bit w/8GB or RAM, and I am able to successfully boot that installer from USB.

What BIOS settings should I have to setup pfSense?

[Their troubleshooting guide](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Boot_Troubleshootin) is unhelpful as all steps here assume the USB load was successful.

Comment: Does the mini PC support BIOS, UEFI or both?

Comment: How can I determine this for certain?

Comment: You should be able to open the bios/uefi settings by pressing `Esc` immediately after powering the pc on, then there are some settings to switch between UEFI and legacy/BIOS mode if supported.

Comment: I have fiddled with just about everything I could think of in BIOS, do you have any specufuc settings to suggest? I can share more details about the options I have available after work.

Comment: The legacy/UEFI option is most likely in the boot order settings or some submenu of it.Do you see anything with "EFI" or "UEFI" if not you most likely only have legacy/BIOS support?